# Inserir em uma tabela de model diferente no CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Estou fazendo um site com carrinho de orçamentos, com o `CakePHP 2.x`.

criei uma tabela estatísticas, fiz o model dela tudo certo porém eu vou fazer uma inserção nela, somente quando eu entrar no detalhe de algum produto.

Quando eu entrar no detalhe do produto eu quero inserir nela o **id do produto** e o **id da categoria** a que ele pertence, junto com a data.

Eu consegui fazer com que ele insira no model a linha com o `saveAll()` porém ele não pega o **id** de nenhum dos dois.

Eu teria que criar um array de alguma maneira para receber essas informações?

Por que eu passei um array assim no `saveAll()`.

```
array(Estatisticas.produto_id = $produto['id'], Estatisticas.categoria_id = $produto['Categoria']['id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Tente algo do tipo assim, no controller de produtos, insira o atributo:

```
public $uses = array(
    'Estatisticas',
    ...
);
```

Na sua action de detalhe de produtos, faça o seguinte:

```
// array com os dados
$salvarEstatisticas = array(
    'produto_id' => $produto['id'],
    'categoria_id' => $produto['Categoria']['id']
);

// Informa que vai ser um novo registro
$this->Estatisticas->create();

// Insere os registros na tabela
$this->Estatisticas->save($salvarEstatisticas);
```

O que você pode tentar também, pra verificar os valores, é um debug antes do create(), assim:

```
debug($salvarEstatisticas);
```

você vê se o resultado é o esperado.